# Can I set closed questions to be ignored?

Tags: feature-request, tagging, closed-questions

I can define tags for questions I don't want to see. But if a question has been closed, there's no tag for this, only a "[closed]" at the end of the question. So I see the question like all other questions on the list (and click on it before noticing the "[closed]" `;-/`). I would like to ignore such questions, at least like questions with ignored tags.

Answer (score 3):

This has been discussed and seemingly declined on meta.stackoverflow.com, the mother meta site of the stackexchange network:

[Can a closed question be given special tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14045/can-a-closed-question-be-given-special-tags)

You might be interested in the option of [adding `closed:0` to any search you perform](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/41843/162565).

Personally, I think closed questions are important and help finding solutions, so they should equally be kept clean. That's why we don't usually delete them. There might even be a question that's injustly closed and needs to be reopened, once you've gained that [privilege](https://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/close-questions). Closed questions might not be as popular or beloved as open questions, but they are important. After all, I'm sure you'll manage to check for a [closed] before clicking on a question, which is about as good as a tag ... `;)`

Comment: Indexing and searching is not the problem. The problem is the overview list e.g. simply http://tex.stackexchange.com/unanswered. I can _dehighlight_ e.g. all questions tagged "{lists}" and these are in other views important too. But closed questions, that are definitely less important to me, because I wouldn't give one more answer to it, are shown like all other questions still waiting for an answer. So why can the user decide which tags are more and which are less important but not that closed questions are less important? That's my question.

Comment: Tags, which you can "ingore", are ([supposed to be](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/294/about-meta-tagging)) topic-specific; it's just natural that there are topics that a user doesn't know a lot about or that they aren't interested in. However, stackexchange wants you to care about closed questions as well, they should still be important to you. Of course you won't be adding answers, but they can still be edited and potentially even reopened. The difference is that tags are _topical_, while closedness is _technical_.

Comment: But shouldn't it be the decision of the user, if he wants to take care on closed questions, like it is the decision of the user, if he wants to take care on topics? There's no doubt, that if I'm searching for help, I should notice even closed questions. But if I only want to help, why should I be forced to take more care into closed questions than in less interesting topics? Isn't this a kind of not needed paternalismn?

Comment: (I'm not saying that I like all this, I'm just trying to argue in the way I imagine these things were intended.) The system encourages users to take care of various questions in several ways: Edit badges, the review page, flags for 10k users, and by displaying closed questions. Even if you don't take any action, you're still made aware that these questions exist. You can't hide closed questions just like you can't say "I don't want to see questions with a score below 5". Look at it this way: topics (= tags) are site-external, while the state of a question is site-internal.

Comment: @Schweinebacke I'm not sure I follow on the unanswered list. It does not show closed questions in general, unless one has just been closed and you take a look. (There seems to be a 'time lag' in several areas, and this is one of them.)

Comment: @Joseph Wright: OK, that's an answer I can follow. If this is simply a timing problem I have to life with.